# Java generics error incompatible type, variable coming from interface causing compilation error

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm implementing a Graph interface called SparseGraph.  When I try to compile, I am getting this error:

```
SparseGraph.java:150: error: edges() in SparseGraph cannot implement edges() in Graph
public Iterable<Edge<E>> edges() {
                         ^
return type Iterable<SparseGraph<V,E#1>.Edge<E#1>> is not compatible with Iterable<Edge<E#1>>


where E#1,V,E#2 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Object declared in class SparseGraph
    V extends Object declared in class SparseGraph
    E#2 extends Object declared in interface Graph
SparseGraph.java:95: error: insert(V#1) in SparseGraph cannot implement insert(V#2) in Graph
    public Vertex<V> insert(V v) {
                     ^
  return type SparseGraph<V#1,E>.Vertex<V#1> is not compatible with Vertex<V#1>
  where V#1,E,V#2 are type-variables:
    V#1 extends Object declared in class SparseGraph
    E extends Object declared in class SparseGraph
    V#2 extends Object declared in interface Graph
```

The corresponding code for this is:

```
public class SparseGraph<V, E> implements Graph<V, E> {
    private final class Vertex<V> {
        Object label;
        ArrayList<Edge<E>> inEdges;
        ArrayList<Edge<E>> outEdges;
        Graph<V, E> owner;
        V data;
        public Vertex() {
            this.inEdges = new ArrayList<Edge<E>>();
            this.outEdges = new ArrayList<Edge<E>>();
       }

       /** Adds incoming edge.
        * @param e is edge to add
        * @return false if edge already exists, true if added sucessfully
        */
       public boolean addInEdge(Edge<E> e) {
           if (this.inEdges.indexOf(e) != -1) {
               return false;
           } else {
               this.inEdges.add(e);
               return true;
           }
       }

    /** Adds outgoing edge.
     * @param e is outgoing edge to add
     * @return false if edge already exists, true if added successfully
     */
    public boolean addOutEdge(Edge<E> e) {
        if (this.outEdges.indexOf(e) != -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            this.outEdges.add(e);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /** Removes edge*/
    public E removeEdge(Edge<E> e) throws PositionException {
        try {
            this.inEdges.remove(e);
            return e.data;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException a) {
            try {
                this.outEdges.remove(e);
                return e.data;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException b) {
                throw new PositionException();
            }
        }
    }
}

     public Vertex<V> insert(V v) {
            Vertex<V> newVertex;
            newVertex = new Vertex<V>();
            newVertex.data = v;
            newVertex.owner = this;
            vertices.add(newVertex);
            return newVertex;
        }

   public Iterable<Edge<E>> edges() {
    ArrayList<Edge<E>> allEdges = new ArrayList<Edge<E>>();
    for (Vertex<V> vertex : this.vertices) {
        for (Edge<E> inEdge : vertex.inEdges) {
            if (allEdges.indexOf(inEdge) == -1) {
                allEdges.add(inEdge);
            }
        }
        for (Edge<E> outEdge : vertex.outEdges) {
            if (allEdges.indexOf(outEdge) == -1) {
                allEdges.add(outEdge);
            }
        }
    }
    return allEdges;
}
```

I've been at this for a while, and I have no idea how to fix this.  Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You need to post more of the code. How are `Vertex`, `Edge` and `SparceGraph` defined?

Comment: Thanks, added that part of the code.

Comment: Please add the code for the `Graph` interface.  Without that, it’s difficult to assist you.